# Calculate and Display Total Experience Months in YY/MM format in Sql Server

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, formatting

Consider the following code.

```
create table #temp (Min_Expr_InMonths int, Max_Expr_InMonths int)

insert into #temp values (40, 98)
insert into #temp values (null, null)
insert into #temp values (0, 0)
insert into #temp values (133, 145)

select ' (Exp - ' +  
    Convert(varchar, Case when j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12 < 10 then '0' + convert(varchar, j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12) else j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12 end) + '/' + 
    Convert(varchar, 
    case when j.Min_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12)*12) < 10 then '0' + convert(varchar, j.Min_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12)*12)) else
    j.Min_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12)*12) end) + ' to ' + Convert(varchar, 
    Case when j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12 < 10 then '0' + convert(varchar, j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12) else j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12 end) + '/' + 
    Convert(varchar, 
    case when j.Max_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12)*12) < 10 then '0' + convert(varchar, j.Max_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12)*12)) else
    j.Max_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12)*12) end) + ')' from #temp j
```

Output of the above query is as follows.

```
YY/MM
(Exp - 3/4 to 8/2)
NULL
(Exp - 0/0 to 0/0)
(Exp - 11/1 to 12/1)
```

What I wanted to achieve is as follows.

```
YY/MM
(Exp - 03/04 to 08/02)
(Exp - 00/00 to 00/00)
(Exp - 00/00 to 00/00)
(Exp - 11/01 to 12/01)
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this, my query looks very untidy and difficult to read, also I am not sure about the performance as the DB rows increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try below simplest query:

```
select 'Exp - ' + 
    right('00' + convert(varchar(2),coalesce(Min_Expr_InMonths,0)/12),2) + '/' +
    right('00' + convert(varchar(2),coalesce(Min_Expr_InMonths,0)%12),2) + ' to '+
    right('00' + convert(varchar(2),coalesce(Max_Expr_InMonths,0)/12),2) + '/' + 
    right('00' + convert(varchar(2),coalesce(Max_Expr_InMonths,0)%12),2) as 'YY/MM'
from #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrected select query:

```
SELECT '(Exp - ' +  
    CASE 
        WHEN j.Min_Expr_InMonths IS NULL 
            THEN '00' 
        WHEN (j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12 >= 10) 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12) 
        ELSE 
            CONCAT('0',CONVERT(VARCHAR, j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12)) 
    END 
        + '/' + 
    CASE 
        WHEN j.Min_Expr_InMonths IS NULL 
            THEN '00' 
        WHEN j.Min_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12)*12) >= 10 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,j.Min_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12)*12)) 
        ELSE
            CONCAT('0',CONVERT(VARCHAR, j.Min_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Min_Expr_InMonths/12)*12))) 
    END 
        + ' to ' + 
    CASE 
        WHEN j.Max_Expr_InMonths IS NULL 
            THEN '00' 
        WHEN j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12 >= 10 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12) 
        ELSE 
            CONCAT('0',j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12) 
    END 
        + '/' + 
    CASE 
        WHEN j.Max_Expr_InMonths IS NULL 
            THEN '00' 
        WHEN j.Max_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12)*12) >= 10 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, j.Max_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12)*12)) 
        ELSE
            CONCAT('0',CONVERT(VARCHAR,j.Max_Expr_InMonths - ((j.Max_Expr_InMonths/12)*12))) 
    END 
        + ')'
FROM #temp j
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(Exp - 03/04 to 08/02)
(Exp - 00/00 to 00/00)
(Exp - 00/00 to 00/00)
(Exp - 11/01 to 12/01)
```

For Demo Follow the link:

> http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d462f3f8cc4b945e01a7d594b016a105

Comment: Thank you soo much, it's working, will it effect the performance when rows increase.